# tense mismatch for a reported fact with "there was"

Tags: tense

> There was a lady who spit at me yesterday.
>
> There was a lady who spat at me yesterday.

Is the first one ungrammatical? I am thinking it is, but I am wondering if there's any situation where the first one is ok grammatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The past tense of the verb 'to spit' is mainly 'spit' in American English, and mainly 'spat' in British English.

[Spit (Oxford Learners Dictionary)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/spit_1)